# sp_executesql inside Try & Catch

Tags: sql-server, try-catch, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

```
Begin Try
Declare @SQL NVarchar(Max)='Exec [MyLinkedServer].master.dbo.sp_executesql N''Drop Table [tempdb].dbo.[T1]''';
Print   @SQL;
Exec master.dbo.sp_executesql @SQL;
End Try
Begin Catch
Print Error_Message()
End Catch
```

The above script fails when the table T1 doesn't exist in MyLinkedServer
instead of being directed to Catch section.
What do I miss?

Just to be clear: the original procedure constructs the @SQL dynamicaly inside a procedure using parameters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, the above script does not fail and works exactly as you expect it:

```
Begin Try
Declare @SQL NVarchar(Max)='Exec [MyLinkedServer].master.dbo.sp_executesql N''Drop Table [tempdb].dbo.[T1]''';
Print   @SQL;
Exec master.dbo.sp_executesql @SQL;
End Try
Begin Catch
print 'in catch'
Print Error_Message()
End Catch

Exec [MyLinkedServer].master.dbo.sp_executesql N'Drop Table [tempdb].dbo.[T1]'
in catch
Could not find server 'MyLinkedServer' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
```

See that 'in catch' message? Is proof that the catch block was executed.

But you are right that there is a well known issue in that compilation errors cannot be caught in the scope they occur. Which is absolutely to be expected, is like asking a catch block in a C# program to run when the code fails to compile... The issue is well explained in great detailed at [Error Handling in SQL 2005 and Later](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html). You have to create an outer scope to catch the compilation error that occurs in the inner scope. Which is exactly what you do in your posted example!

Comment: Thank you, but you have a different error: you don't have a linked server whose name is MyLinkedServer, and such a local error is handled by the Try & Catch.

Comment: Is you XACT_ABORT ON or OFF? See [Handling Errors in Server-to-Server Remote Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191515.aspx).

Comment: I Tried both options and the results are just the same.

Comment: I Tried both options and the results are just the same.
What is seemed very strange is that the same code with 'create table [tempdb].dbo.[T1](I Int)' when it already exists (severity 11) works fine, but with 'Drop table [tempdb].dbo.[T1]' (severity 16) fails.

Thank you very much for your help.